# SearchBar Renderer Changes not applying

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, renderer

```
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SearchBar), typeof(RCI.iOS.SearchBarRenderer))]
namespace RCI.iOS
{
  public class SearchBarRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.SearchBarRenderer
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
      if(Control != null)
      {
        Control.Text = "Help Me!";
        Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 0;
        Control.TintColor = UIKit.UIColor.White;
        Control.SetPositionAdjustmentforSearchBarIcon(UIOffset.Zero, UISearchBarIcon.Search);
      }

      base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a custom renderer for my search bar. I am working with Xamarin.Forms iOS and have made renderers previously for this project. But for some reason i can not get these changes to apply to my searchBar.

Comment: Is the code being executed when you place a breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, If I add a breakpoint this code gets hit.

Comment: please delete.  Adding full, formatted comment below

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which result you're not seeing applied. I'm guessing the background color is not changing to white as you are expecting. You have to apply a stupid trick of of loading a blank image iOS so that default coloring of the searchbar is overriden. Add the following to your FinishedLaunching method in your appDelegate and you should be good.

```
UISearchBar.Appearance.BackgroundImage = new UIImage();
```